What is the Manchester style encoding of gene-protein associations
From SBML Level 3 Package: Flux Balance Constraints (`fbc'), page 11

A GeneProduct may, optionally, refer to a Species so as to provide compatibility with the Manchester style encoding of gene-protein associations.

I suspect it is to just represent proteins as a Species on both sides of the reactions they participate in.
